# Is there an option in Lightroom for listing the missing (questionmarked) photos?

Tags: lightroom, lightroom-4

I am looking for a way to list or filter out the photos that are reported as missing or offline. I have seen at least two photos in Library with a question mark. The folder itself didn't have a question mark and not all of the photos in the folder had the question mark. I thought I would fix it later. But now I can't locate that particular photo in Library because I have many folders and about 7400 photos to go through to locate that particular photo or photos with question marks.

There must be a better way! Is there no way to filter missing or offline photos in Lightroom? I mean the same way you would filter photos with a particular flag, rating or color label? You just go to Library, click Attribute, and then click on one of the flag icons (picked/unflagged/rejected) and Lightroom will show you the photos with those attributes. Can you do something like that for missing photos (i.e. photos with a question mark)?

Comment: Just for clarity, are you using LR 4, or 5?

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/lightroom/using/WS3BC0B0A1-D48C-4271-891D-DA04EF388E29.html

Comment: @Tortilla Yes, I am using Lightroom 4.

Comment: Updated the question as the accepted answer didn't answer the question title as stated but did answer the long form question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the Library module, try Library -> Find All Missing Photos. I have LR 5, so I know it's in there. I don't know about LR 4.

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for it at the Library Filter bar. I forgot to check the Library **menu**. I just found 77 photos. I will fix these immediately, before I forget. I believe these photos have been previously deleted from within LR. I can see that some of them are even flagged as rejected. I usually delete rejected photos. But for some reason... the thumbnails/previews for these photos have been left behind, i.e. they have not been deleted from the catalog. Strange...

Comment: Sometimes I'll accidentally get rid of the original DNG and leave an orphaned preview like that. It's good to run that command now and then to see if your library is accounted for.

Comment: Although this is an old thread, still useful to me. Thanks